# A reference in the chapter title that doesn't show up in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, citing, chapters

I have been searching for a while, but I didn't find what I was looking for. If this question has been answered before please add a link to the answer.

I am writing a report, where every chapter is a published article that I discuss. I want to cite each article in the title of its corresponding chapter, but I don't want the reference number to be shown in the table of contents.

I tried

`\chapter{Paths \cite{...}}`

The chapter title looks fine with the citation number beside it for example,

**Paths [1]**

but it also shows like this in the table of contents, and that is what I don't want. I want to show up in the table of contents only as

**Paths**

Is this possible?

Or there another better way to do it? Maybe put a header just for the citation number?

Comment: You can use the optional argument: `\chapter[Paths]{Paths \cite{...}}`. But I'd rather add the citation _after_ `\chapter`, as part of the text.

Comment: Thank you,
Also where can I learn about these options (\..[options]{...}),  I tried many sites but none helped :-/